# Use Google Analytics and Firebase Remote Config together in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics-sdk, firebase-remote-config

I am using **Google analytics** in my iOS app. Now we are planning to use **Firebase Remote config** in the app. But I am not being able to use both in same app as both requires `GoogleService-Info.plist` and I do not find any way to rename one of it and use both. Also I do not find a way to add both properties in same `GoogleService-Info.plist`. Is there any other way to use both **Google Analytics and Firebase together?**

Comment: use any one of the file and add the other file keys to the one you are using

Answer (score 0):

Got this issue resolved by importing google analytics account into firebase. It will generate  GoogleService-Info.plist with both configuration details. Also make sure that your client id is in GoogleService-Info.plist is same as google analytics. Keep rest of the coding same and add Firebase events which are required.